# How to get metadata using BlockBlobClient.getProperties in azure storage javascript SDK for browser

Tags: javascript, azure, sdk, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to get the metadata for a particular blob using the azure storage javascript SDK. Here is my code:

```
private returnBlobMetadata(filename: string, container: string) {
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`${this.sasData.storageUri}?${this.sasData.storageAccessToken}`);
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(container);
    const blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(filename);
    return from(blobClient.getProperties());
}
```

When I subscribe to the output of this function I get a response. However, my metadata is empty, despite the metadata being present in the portal, every other entity is also empty. I also am able to receive the metadata when listing blobs within a container.

Here is my response:

[image: Azure Storage response]

Any help you could give me would be very much appreciated as I've been tearing my hair out at this one.

**EDIT**
On inspection of the headers, I can see that it is present there a x-ms-meta-filename however.

```
   Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Expose-Headers: content-length
    Content-Length: 67961
    Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2020 11:41:08 GMT
    ETag: "0x8D7EB1A5E0E88CF"
    Last-Modified: Tue, 28 Apr 2020 02:17:57 GMT
    Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
    x-ms-access-tier: Hot
    x-ms-access-tier-inferred: true
    x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
    x-ms-client-request-id: **id**
    x-ms-creation-time: Tue, 28 Apr 2020 01:50:06 GMT
    x-ms-lease-state: available
    x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
    x-ms-meta-filename: Curriculum Vitae.pdf <-- this is what I want
    x-ms-request-id: 4d87bf9c-901e-0089-5551-1d8136000000
    x-ms-server-encrypted: true
    x-ms-version: 2019-02-02
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is always better to paste the response as text instead of image. Can you expand `_response` and see if metadata is returned in there. If that's the case then it may very well be a bug in the SDK.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. No in the _response.parsed_headers.metadata the value is still an empty object {}. Whereas it should have a metadata tag of 'filename': 'name of file'.

Comment: Can you trace the request/response in browser's networking tab (under developer's tools)?

Comment: Yeah I can, is there any information in particular you need to know from there?

Comment: Just check the response headers please. You should see metadata in there.

Comment: Okay I have edited the question above, yes it is in my headers as x-ms-meta-filename. I am using an angular application, could that be blocking the header?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

If anyone else is suffering the same issue here is the answer. The expose headers option was not set in the azure portal. This meant that the headers were not exposed to the frontend and my application could not read them. When I set them to all this fixed my problem.

[image: Image of solution]